# monacaでテンプレート上でjavascriptが効かない

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, html5

monacaのテンプレート「Onsen UI Sliding Menu」を編集しているのですが、[PAGE2.html]に埋め込みのjavascriptを記載したのですが動作しません。index.html内では動作しますので何が原因なのかわからない状態です。お助けお願い致します。

```
<script>
    alert("アラート");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAGE2.htmlに移動するにあたって、アンカータグ（リンク）や、window.location.hrefを書き換えて移動するのであれば、PAGE2.htmlのscriptタグは動作すると思います。
けれども、Onsen UIでシングルページアプリケーション(SPA)として移動する場合は、index.htmlがPAGE2.htmlを「読み込んで」表示しているだけなので、PAGE2.htmlに記載したscriptタグは動作しません。pageinitイベントを検出して動作するように作り変えてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 大変参考になりました。index.htmlにはヘッダー等があるのにPAGE2.htmlにはなかったのもこの仕組みの為だったんですね！一気にすっきりしました！ありがとうございます。